# JSP Struts reverse iterator

Tags: jsp, iterator, struts

I got a jsp page where Struts iterator is used to fetch items from the db.

Is there some way reverse the order of the result set?

Note: I don't have the source code, hence can't do it via the class and re-compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`<logic:iterate>`](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-logic.html#iterate) tag isn't very flexible in this regard. It is just an iterator exposed as a tag. So the only way to reverse the result set is to do it before reaching the tag (i.e. reverse the collection of results higher in the application layers (with something like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) or similar) and use the `<logic:iterate>` tag on this (already) reversed collection).

If you need to reverse the collection in the JSP then maybe the JSTL [`<c:forEach>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) tag could work, something like:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" begin="${fn:length(items) - 1}" end="0" step="-1">
  ....
</c:forEach>
```

If you don't like any of the above, then maybe you could [write yourself whatever type of tag](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tutorial/TagLibrariesTOC.html) iterator you want.